# Default Nginx Configuration breaks Other Configurations

Tags: nginx

I have a default nginx configuration in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

My /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

`server {
  listen      80 default_server; # add 443 / SSL if you like
  server_name _; # I tried without this line too
  return      404;

}`

My /etc/nginx/sites-available/site.tld

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html/directory;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    set $vname site.tld;
    server_name $vname www.$vname;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
```

}

The website works fine but, the issue is I can access directly from the IP too which I do not want.

When I run the command `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

I get a 404 when accessing the website as well as the direct IP.

PS: This is my first question on StackOverflow/ServerFault.

Thanks for the help, I've been trying to fix this problem for a few hours now.

Comment: Your `server_name` statement contains variables. I don't think Nginx allows variables in `server_name`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed the issue,